# Display each picture in a specific folder in order

Tags: c#

I have 5 pictures in a folder inside C:\

The pictures are named pic(1) to (5)

I want the program to display the first picture inside that folder then go to the next.

I can do it by declaring a string "path" and an int "nextNumb" and build a code inside a timer where the "nextNumb" will increase each time the code runs and change the path from (1) to (2) to (3) and so on...

But this is unefficient I wanted to somehow read/open the pictures inside the folder and display them in the order they are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all files in a directory with this command "Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a example to extract the number of your file and sort by the number

```
static void Main()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"your Path");
    var items = files.OrderBy(o => ExtractNumber(o)).ToList();
}

private static int ExtractNumber(string filePath)
{
    //file name structure -> "pic(1).jpg"

    var startIndex = filePath.IndexOf('(');
    if (startIndex == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    var endIndex = filePath.IndexOf(')', startIndex);
    if (endIndex == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    var tempNumber = filePath.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1);
    if (int.TryParse(tempNumber, out int fileNumber))
    {
        return fileNumber;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I tried to but there seems to be a problem with it, whenever I read all the files in the directory, creating a var filepath which is Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory) and try to read each file using foreach file in filepath, it starts normal displaying the first picture, then it jumps to the last. I tried with more pictures (300). It jumps from 1 to 10 then from 10 to 100 and it keeps doing these weird jumps. Delaying the task does not help

Comment: Also when the numbers are 100 or more it keeps going back for some reason, it would go 100..101...102... to 109 then it goes back to 11 and after a while resumes with the next number being 110

Comment: @PedroRibeiro: This sounds like the normal sort behaviour when sorting numbers as string. _Example_ `var numbers = new List<string> { "1", "9", "10", "90", "100", "109", "110" };`
 `var sortNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(t => t);`
_sortNumbers:_
`OrderedEnumerable<string, string> { "1", "10", "100", "109", "110", "9", "90" }`